# Why do we integrate to obtain prior distributions?

Tags: bayesian, prior, integral

In the test for difference in means with unknown variance, it's stated that in order to obtain prior distributions, we have to take the double integral with respect to mean and to the variance? However, I can not understand the sense behind this step. Why do we integrate to obtain them?

[image]

Comment: Where does the text say anything about "in order to obtain prior distributions"?  You are integrating to find the Bayes factor, not the prior distributions, which must be specified *before* you perform the integration.

Comment: Please allocate the text to the author by providing a reference and a link.

Comment: And I would suggest reading any Bayesian textbook, like for instance [McElreath (2015)](https://amzn.to/2XXaw1N) to try to understand the fundamentals of Bayesian modelling and inference.